# How to prove the real points of affine variety defined over the reals is a differentiable manifold?

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, reference-request

Let $V$ be an affine algebraic set defined as a zero set of real polynomials. Then $V \cap \mathbb{R}^n \backslash V^*$ defines a differentiable manifold according to Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiable_manifold. Here $V^*$ is the set of singular points. 
I have been taking this fact for granted, but realized not sure how to actually prove it. I would greatly appreciate comments and references.

PS I would greatly appreciate a reference for this also!

Comment: I'm not sure what $V^{*}$ means, to most of what you've written...but (1) surely there are some conditions you've left out, for in the plane, the set $x^2 = y^3$ has a non-manifold point, and (2) once you've got those conditions nailed down, then general fact that you need is the implicit function theorem.

Comment: @JohnHughes regarding V^* fixed.

Comment: How does it follow from the implicit function theorem though? How does one know that everything with atlases and transition maps all work?

Comment: First you show (using IFT) that every point has a neighborhood that's nice, and for which projection to (at least) one of the coordinate planes is a coord chart. For overlapping neighborhoods with identical projection planes, transition functions are clearly nice [they're the identity map on that plane!]. For ones with differing planes, you need to do a (very little) work. You might try working out all the details for, say, the unit circle in the plane, using charts whose width (along one of the axes or the other) is approximately $1/4$. It's instructive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The non-singular real points of $V$ form a Nash manifold (of dimension $\dim(V)$) which is a stronger notion. A reference is Proposition 3.3.11 of Bochnak, Coste, Roy, *Real algebraic geometry*. As mentioned in the comments, the argument is plugging the definition of non-singular points into the implicit function theorem.